# Simple Random Walk with set probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

i have been attempting to do this problem as part of an exam review but having some trouble

Let {Xn} be a simple random walk on the integers with a probability of .4 of moving to the right.

a) If X0 = 3, find the probability that the walk ever reaches 8.

b) If X0 = 1, find the probability that the walk ever reaches -10.

c) Now consider the same random walk, but with a reflecting boundary at 6. If X0 = 4, what is the expected number of steps until the walk reaches 3?

So far I have found this formula: (1 -(q/p)^x)/(1-(q/p)^a) and found that question a could be 0.0964 and question b was infinite as it came up to be a negative number

Comment: "question b was infinite as it came up to be a negative number" -- What does it even mean for a question to be infinite?  (yes, I'm being a bit facetious, but as question b is asking for a probability, it definitely can't be infinite)

Comment: Hi: For the first two questions, you just need the binomial frmework. Think about what would have to happen for the RW to reach 8 or -10. In the first case, how many more right moves would you need compared to left moves. Similarly, for the second case, how many more left moves would you need compared to right moves. Then, once you have those, you can calculate the probabilities using the binomial distribution. The third question is different and more difficult but that's a method for solving the first two.